# How to use flowtype in common js with .js.flow style

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am using .js.flow style for flow type checking, but cannot get it running.

I am using CommonJS due to project limitation.

```js
/*--------  state.js -------------*/

//@flow
module.exports = newstate;
function newstate() {
    return {
      name: 'a name'
    }
}

/*--------  state.js.flow -------------*/
//@flow
declare var exports: () => {
 name: string
}

/*--------  main.js -------------*/
//@flow
var getstate = require('../state');
var a = getstate();
a.name = "123";
```

When I running the above code ('flow main.js'), it run type check successfully, and if I change `a.name = "123"` ==> `a.name = 123`, it can detect the type error successfully.

The only thing bother me is, every time I run flow type check, it complain as following:

```
> node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js

path/to/project/state.js.flow:2
  2: declare var exports: () => {
                          ^ function type. Callable signature not found in
exports


Found 1 error
```

Which part did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved it. But you to use the `declare var exports:...` you need to declare it inside a module.

```
declare module state {
  declare var exports: () => { name: string }
}
```

Or by using `declare module.exports: () => { name: string }`

But you could also not use the state.js.flow as you already have `@flow` in your state.js file and flow can infer the types

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it